# Hangfire RecurringJob synchronized with the clock

Tags: c#, cron, hangfire

I'm trying to synchronize a Hangfire recurring job with the clock. Basically, I want to have a recurring job starting by the next hour and then on each hour.

Example: if the current time is 9:04 PM, the recurring job should be as following:
10:00 PM -> 11:00 PM, 00:00 AM, 01:00 AM, 02:00 AM, etc.

It is similar to my previous question: [C# Timer ticking on each rounded hour (literally)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498658/c-sharp-timer-ticking-on-each-rounded-hour-literally?noredirect=1#comment101476015_57498658), but using Hangfire.

In the code below, I tried to make it first by scheduling a `BackgroundJob` for the minutes left until the next hour and then `RecurringJob` for each hour after `BackgroundJob` was executed. The problem is that it ticks at random times.

```
private DateTime RoundCurrentToNextOneHour()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now, result = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, 0, 0);
    return result.AddMinutes(((now.Minute / 60) + 1) * 60);
}

public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Timed Background Service is starting.");

    BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => StartRecurringJob(), RoundCurrentToNextOneHour());

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

public void StartRecurringJob()
{
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => DoWork(), Cron.Hourly, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
}
```

Comment: How random?  Seconds or minutes kinda random?

Comment: Randomly like it doesn't happen exactly in the next hour but a few minutes later after that hour. I did test on each 5 minutes: 09:35 PM, 09:40 PM, 09:45 PM, etc. and it wasn't accurate.

Comment: Your math seems off.  `now.Minute` can only return values in the range `0-59`.  Thus `now.Minute / 60` is always `0`, and thus you are always adding `60` minutes regardless of the input.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint, I have no clue but I modified it to be on each 5 minutes: `return result.AddMinutes(((now.Minute / 5) + 1) * 5);` and that's the result: `Timed Background Service is starting. Current time: 8/15/2019 9:52:48 PM
Timed Background Service is working. Current time: 8/15/2019 9:53:04 PM
Timed Background Service is working. Current time: 8/15/2019 9:54:04 PM`. The first tick is supposed to be at 9:55 and it is at 9:53:04 which is wrong. And by the way the recurring job is happening on each minute, so it's correct. What's not correct is the first tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line of code, you are *always* adding 60 minutes.

```
result.AddMinutes(((now.Minute / 60) + 1) * 60)
```

This is because the `Minute` property can only be in the values 0 through 59, and thus reduces as:

```
result.AddMinutes((0 + 1) * 60)
result.AddMinutes(1 * 60)
result.AddMinutes(60)
```

Try this instead:

```
result.AddMinutes((60 - (now.Minute % 60)) % 60)
```

For example, `09:00` will come out as `09:00`, but `09:01` through `09:59` will round up to `10:00`.  It sounds like this was the behavior you were asking for.

You might also want to read [in the HangFire docs](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/calling-methods-with-delay.html) about the `SchedulePollingInterval`, which could affect your results.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to do that using cron expressions. If you open https://crontab.guru and try out some expressions, you will find an explanation for each of them.

A few examples with cron expressions:

- on each 5 minutes: `0/5 * * * *`.

If the current time was 11:12 PM, it would execute a method at 11:15 PM, then at 11:20 PM and so on.

- on each hour would be `0 * * * *`.

If the current time was 11:12 PM, it would execute a method at 00:00 AM, 01:00 AM, 02:00 AM and so on

In addition to the cron expressions, there are built-in cron expressions. Their source code is here: https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/9cd09f38fa97e4c2dd48f6097985fd2b48b4568e/src/Hangfire.Core/Cron.cs#L231. If I wanted to do some action on each 1 hour, it would be `Cron.Hourly()`.

Example code is given below:

```
RecurringJobManager manager = new RecurringJobManager();
manager.RemoveIfExists("myjob");

// Each 5 minutes, e.g. 01:05 pm, 01:10 pm, 01:15 pm, etc.
//manager.AddOrUpdate("myjob", Job.FromExpression(() => DoWork()), $"0/5 * * * *", TimeZoneInfo.Local);

// Each 1 hour, e.g. 01:00 pm, 02:00, 03:00 pm, etc.
manager.AddOrUpdate("myjob", Job.FromExpression(() => DoWork()), $"0 * * * *", TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

Comment: By running it on each 5 minutes, it seems to have some drift over the time. Perhaps it might be because the chron expression doesn't contain `seconds` and when it increments it by 5, it doesn't take the seconds into account which later leads to a drift over the time. However, I think it will be fine on each hour, because the chron expression basically says tick `at minute 0`. I would like to get a more competent explanation on that and if someone finds a solution.